# One question regarding independence of $\pi$ systems.

Tags: probability-theory

Let G and H be sub-sigma-algebras of F and I and J are $\pi$ systems such that

$\sigma(I)=G$ and $\sigma(J)=H$

Can anyone explain the following quote?

> Suppose I and J are independent, for fixed I, the measures $H \mapsto \mathbb{P}(I \cap H)$ and $H \mapsto \mathbb{P}(I)\mathbb{P}(H)$
>    on ($\Omega$, H) have the same total mass $\mathbb{P}(I)$ and agree on J.

Why is I$\cap$H in ($\Omega$, H) and why does it have a well-defined probability? What does it mean when people say the two measures have the same total mass?

[image]

Comment: your notation is a little confused, the second $H$ is supposed to be an arbitrary measurable set and not $\sigma(J)$. Anyway the total mass of the measure $\mu$ on space $\Omega$ is $\mu(\Omega)$

Comment: That is exactly the notation used in the book portability with martingales. Can you put your comment in an answer?

Comment: I'd have made it an answer if it answered your question... the measure you want is a map from $S$ in the set algebra to the reals $S \mapsto \mathbb{P}(I \cap S)$

Comment: What confuses me is that $I$ is supposed to be a $\pi$ system, i.e. a COLLECTION of measurable sets, not a single measurable set, so how is the expression $I \cap H$ even defined? You can't take the intersection of a single set with a collection of sets and get a single set -- you could get a collection of sets (called the trace), but that still wouldn't work, since probabilities are only defined as functions of a single set, not of collections of sets. Do you mean $\displaystyle\mathbb{P}\left[ \left(\bigcup_{A \in I} A\right) \cap H\right]$ or something like that?

Comment: @William I posted the lemma and proof from the book I was reading. I hope this helps clear things up a bit.

Comment: "Why is I$\cap$H in ($\Omega$, H)" Never said in the text, and actually  I$\cap$H is in $\mathcal F$. "and why does it have a well-defined probability?" Because it is in $\mathcal F$. "What does it mean when people say the two measures have the same total mass?" The total mass of a measure $\mu$ on the measurable space $(X,\mathcal X)$ is $\mu(X)$. Any other question?

Comment: Oh I see, you meant $I$ and $\mathcal{I}$ (\mathcal{I})

Comment: @William now that the confusion is cleared. Can you put together your comment as an answer?

Comment: I don't think my comment answered the question at all, just expressed confusion, although I thought @Did's comment did address your question -- is there anything in that comment you are still unsure about?

Comment: @William Which comment are you referring?

Comment: I quote " 
"Why is $I \cap H$ in $(\Omega, H)$" Never said in the text, and actually I∩H is in $\mathcal{F}$. "and why does it have a well-defined probability?" Because it is in $\mathcal{F}$. "What does it mean when people say the two measures have the same total mass?" The total mass of a measure μ on the measurable space $(X,\mathcal{X})$ is $\mu(X)$. Any other question?"